# Placing points in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n$ points in $\Bbb R^n$, suppose we arrange the points as an $n\times n$ matrix, when does the matrix have rank $r$? I am looking for a more intuitive geometric explanation (not the usual expressing every point as a linear combination explanation of $r$ points explanation).

Comment: When there is a set of $r$ points among those $n$ points, using which you can express all the $n$ points as a linear combination. Moreover, there is no other set smaller in size which can do the same.

Comment: The rank is the maximal number of independent column vectors, right? Now when are two vectors (starting at the origen) linearly independent in $\mathbb R^n$, geometrically speaking...?

Comment: When they are joined by a line, they do not pass the origin. How to generalize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix has rank $\le r$ if and only if all the points lie in an $r$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Can we think of this as a codim n-r hyperplane passing through origin?

Comment: @Turbo: Yes, if that makes it easier for you: a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ is the same thing as a hyperplane passing through the origin.